# Does setAlias() require a defined background?

Tags: canvas, paint

Am I correct in assuming the reason my use of 'paint.setAlias(true)' has no effect on my circles is because I haven't explicitly assigned a color to the background of the canvas?

Comment: You didn't specify what language you're using or library to invoke the `setAlias()` function, please provide more context.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about java? If you are, no. The background does not affect the setAlias() function.

Please try to be more specific when doing a question.

Comment: apologies - I'm using android studio and java...and the circle i'm trying to apply antialiasing to is a simple primitive using drawCircle().